# spring boot json to model conversion error

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

```
{
  "cust":"A",
  "del":[{
    "type1": "id",
    "type2":[{
        "name":"address"
    }]
}]
```

I have converted this json to below model class

```
public class Del{
    public String type1;
    public JSONArray type2; // "type2" has dynamic key and value which are string, it can have "name":"address","id":"sal" pair etc dynamically
}

public class Root{
    public String cust;
    public List<Del> del;
}
```

But, this mapping is showing error. how to fetch key and value inside "type2" in dynamic way where attribute names are not fixed.

Comment: `List<Map<String, String>>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list, you need a `List<T>`. What is `T`? If it can have any number of keys, then it must be a `Map<K, V>`. `K` is `String`, and `V` is either `String` or `Object`, depending on your actual structure. If you have a handful of expected keys and want to ignore everything else, make `T` a custom class of yours:

```java
class Type2Props {
  public String name;
  public String address;
  public String id;
  public String sal;
}
```

Properties/fields without a value in the JSON will be left initialized as `null`.

Putting it together, you either need

```java
public class Del {
    public String type1;
    public List<Type2Props> type2;
}
```

or

```java
public class Del {
    public String type1;
    public List<Map<String, String>> type2; /* might be `Map<String, Object>` */
}
```